# JavaScript shuffling algorithm explanation

Tags: javascript

I've found shuffling algorithm seems work fine.

```js
const questions = [
  { name: "Ananda or Nalanda" },
  { name: "Sunny or Rainy" },
  { name: "Facebook or Instagram" },
  { name: "IOS or Android" },
  { name: "Mc or KFC" }
];

questions.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)

questions.forEach(e=>{
    console.log(e.name)
})
```

But I couldn't think how this work in the syntax. I know that `Math.random()` will generate a number between 0 and 1. Also sort is standard function to sort. But how do these two functions shuffle my array? Why does it deduct 0.5 from `Math.random()`?

Comment: Documentation on MDN sort of explains it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return value from the `.sort` callback is expected to be a positive number, 0, or a negative number. So, subtracting `0.5` from a variable with a range of `[0, 1)` results in a range of `[-0.5, 0.5)` - an equal distribution of randomly sorting `a` before `b`, and of sorting `b` before `a` (where `a` and `b` are the elements being compared). This *kind of* randomly sorts the array, by randomly determining whether an `a` comes before or after a `b`.

If you didn't subtract 0.5, or subtracted something other than 0.5, the results would be significantly biased.

BUT, this is not a *good* way to randomly sort an array; the results here will be somewhat biased as well:

```js
// an array of 'a' to 'f'
const questions = Array.from(
  { length: 6 },
  (_, i) => String.fromCharCode(i + 97)
);

const positionFrequency = {};
for (let i = 0; i < 1e5; i++) {
  const sorted = questions.slice().sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  sorted.forEach((char, i) => {
    if (!positionFrequency[char]) {
      positionFrequency[char] = {};
    }
    positionFrequency[char][i] = (positionFrequency[char][i] || 0) + 1;
  });
}
console.log(positionFrequency);
```

Please run the snippet - it is *very* biased! In Chrome, `a` occurs in the first position some 28% of the time, despite the fact that it *should* occur there only 1/6th (16.667%) of the time. In Firefox 56, it's even more biased than that.

This is because the sorting algorithm is not *stable* - the results depend on which elements are compared against which other elements first (which is implementation-dependent). You can read more details about how exactly this kind of random-sorting is biased here:

http://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html

Answer (score 1):

Array.sort sorts an array given a compare function. The `sort` function compares all the items in the array using the compare function to determine which ones should go before other ones. The compare function must return a negative, zero, or positive value. It uses this value to determine which value should go first.

For example, when comparing values `a` and `b`, the sort function will call `compare_function(a, b)` and if it returns a negative value, `sort` will place `a` before `b` in the final sorted array. If the compare function returns a positive value, `sort` will place `a` after `b`.

So in your example, `Math.random() - 0.5` is the compare function. Because `Math.random()` normally returns a value between `0` and `1`, `Math.random() - 0.5` will return a random number between `-0.5` and `0.5`. Therefore, the chance that the compare function (which is `Math.random() - 0.5`) will return a positive number is the *same as the chance that* the compare function will return a negative value.

In other words, a random number between `-0.5` and `+0.5` is used to determine whether an arbitrary item `a` in your array goes before or after an item `b`. And because the chances of a positive versus negative number being used are the same, the chances of `a` before `b` versus `b` before `a`, in the sorted array, are the same.

I hope this answer is helpful!